# add ICollection User in the same entity User

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

Whether it is possible so: it is a Messenger where the entity User content ICollection User that are collection Friends consist from the same Users?
If that possible please tell me how create a correct relationship between them in the DbContext file?
Or how better build this relationship. May be create separate entity?
Thanks in advance!

```
namespace Tinkl.Data.Core.Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Contacts = new List<User>();
            Conversations = new List<Conversation>();
            Invites = new List<User>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string NickName { get; set; }
        public string EMail { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExitDate { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Invites { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Contacts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem: createв only one common collection for all Users

Answer (score 1):

You are going in right direction, see my below code same type of self-relationship in EF code first

```
public class ContentEntityRef : BaseModel
{
    public ContentEntityRef()
    {
        RoleRefs = new HashSet<RoleRef>();
    }

    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public int? ParentEntityId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoleRef> RoleRefs { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentEntityRef Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContentEntityRef> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I had created seprate configuration file, you can same use in dbContext "OnModelCreating" method.

```
internal class ContentEntityRefConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContentEntityRef>, IEntityConfiguration
{
    public ContentEntityRefConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.EntityId).Property(t => t.EntityId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(x => x.EntityName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

        this.HasMany(c => c.Children).WithOptional(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentEntityId);

        this.HasMany<RoleRef>(role => role.RoleRefs)
           .WithMany(content => content.ContentEntities)
           .Map(contentRole =>
           {
               contentRole.MapLeftKey("EntityID");
               contentRole.MapRightKey("RoleID");
               contentRole.ToTable("RoleEntityMap");
           });
    }
}
```

hope this will help you :)